# Bash snippet to move all files in a directory into that directory

Tags: linux, unix, bash

I have a directory with lots of files and directories in it. In order to tidy it up, I'm going to put all those files into a directory, so I was going to do something like this:

```
$ ls | wc -l
123
$ mkdir new_directory
$ mv * ./new_directory
```

However that obviously won't work because then it'll try to move `new_directory` into `new_directory`. Is there some simple way to do what I want in one line without me having to copy and paste all the files and directories in that directory?

Comment: it works, it just prints an error message that it's unable to move new_directory into itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your

```
mv * ./new_directory
```

command will actually work; it'll just print a warning that it can't move that directory into itself.

Comment: The 'only' problem with this is that if the total expansion of the command becomes too long (i.e. too many files, too long names) this will no longer work.

Comment: As a side note, if you're going to do this with a `git mv` you must use the `-k` flag, since git will fail by default, not just spit out a warning. So you'll need to do `git mv -k * ./new_dir`.

Answer (score 11):

A fast and dirty oneliner.

```
mv `ls -A | grep -v new_directory` ./new_directory
```

Comment: Will not work: a plain ls will not show dotfiles.

Comment: Very good point. Fixed that with an -a.

Comment: So instead of trying to mv new_directory to itself (Original question) you are now trying to move . and .. into new_directory.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Niels. Fixed it with an upper a which removes the . and the .. from the directory listing.

Answer (score 8):

If you're just looking for the files (i.e. not directories), then

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec mv {} ./new_directory/ \;
```

is the most portable solution. For speed, you should move find and xargs, with -print0 and -0, but only if you've got GNU find and xargs.

Comment: Using a fairly recent GNU find, you could also use \+ instead of \; to decrease the number of mv's we are making.

Comment: If you've got GNU find, you're as well to use xargs, which'll do the same, and let you run multiple mvs at the same time with the -p flag.

Comment: cool use of `find` - though I've definitely been on systems that don't have one, sadly :(

Comment: Really? find is (afaik) specified in SUS, so *everything* should have it. The only issue is whether it's GNU find (which has lots of nice cool options) or regular find.

Comment: Yep, it appears to be http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html

Comment: then i've been on some systems that have had findutils (or similar) yoinked for whatever reason. Not saying it's good - but I've seen it happen <shrug>

Comment: @Cian: it's `-P` *max-procs* (uppercase), not `-p`. `-p` is a synonym for `--interactive`.

Answer (score 6):

The times that I've had this problem, I've done one of the following:

```
$ mkdir ../new-directory
$ mv * ../new-directory/
$ mv ../new-directory .
```

or

```
$ mkdir .new-directory
$ mv * .new-directory/
$ mv .new-directory new-directory
```

The second form takes advantage of the wildcard skipping filenames that start with '.'

Comment: I forgot the wild-card skipped dotted files; thanks for the reminder ! :)

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
cd ..
mv old_dir new_directory
mkdir old_dir
mv new_directory old_dir
```

IOW, don't move the contents into a new directory, but put this directory inside a new one.

Answer (score 1):

In similar fashion to @[Rembrane](https://serverfault.com/questions/63269/bash-snippet-to-move-all-files-in-a-directory-into-that-directory/63273#63273)'s answer (though not a one-liner):

```
for FN in *
do
    if [ "<new_dir>" != $FN ] then
        mv $FN <new_dir>
done
```

This should be 100% portable - even if `find` is sadly absent from your system.

Comment: find is required in the single unix spec. As such, it should never be absent (not that you couldn't build something with out it. But I'd imagine it'd require a horrendous amount of effort, and no vendor system will lack it)

Comment: maybe it's some hyper-paranoid sysadmin yoinking findutils or its equivalent? not sure, but I know I've run into boxen that don't have it :(

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:
As stated by others the

```
mv * ./new_directory
```

will work find IFF the total expansion is short enough.

Other wise you can try this one that scales to much much larger numbers of files:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs -s100000 echo | xargs -iXXX mv XXX new_directory
```

Explanation

1. List all files.
2. Group all filesnames into chunks of max 100000 chars.
3. Construct a single mv command per chunk.

Comment: breaks if you've got any spaces in your file names

Comment: You're right. So i guess this should be augmented with -print0 and -0 flags to fix.

Comment: I've tried with `-print0` and `-0` and it still breaks.

Comment: find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \! -name new_directory -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -P 100 -I'{}' mv '{}' new_directory
```

From the `xargs` man page:

> -P max-procs
>
> ```
>   Run up to max-procs processes at a time;
> ```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the error message and keep it simple:

```
mv *.* ./new_Folder
```

will do the same thing but avoid the error message (unless you have dots in your folder names I guess).